# Trouble setting up Gandi custom domain name with heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to set custom domain name to my heroku app. I bought a domain name on gandi, then I created a new version of the gandi zone file linked to my domain and finally I made the www point to my heroku app. I then activated the relevant file zone :
[image]

I also set my app config with my custom domaine name :

[image]

I waited for more than a day and when I m trying to enter my url, this is what I get :
[image]

Do you know what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Gandi DNS quickbed.org zone settings, instead of

```
www.quickbed.org CNAME quickbedlanding.herokuapp.com
```

you need just

```
www CNAME quickbedlanding.herokuapp.com
```

(your current entry will result in `www.quickbed.org.quickbed.org` being pointed at `quickbedlanding.herokuapp.com`)

Comment: getting this message now :
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: As far as I can [see](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/www.quickbed.org), your current setting for `www` is `CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net`